# Validate only if phone number is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I can validate the phone_number for uniqueness like this in the model :

```
validates :phone_number, :uniqueness => true
```

The problem is that none of the users in the database have a phone number, and so they are all empty. While loading the page, without entring any phone number, I keep getting the following validation error :

```
Validation failed: Phone number has already been taken
```

Seems like it's even applying the validation for empty phone numbers.

How can I modify the validation to only apply to non-empty phone numbers in the params ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either this:

```
validates :phone_number, :uniqueness => true, :allow_nil => true
```

passes if phone_number is *nil* (or NULL in database), or this:

```
validates :phone_number, :uniqueness => true, :allow_blank => true
```

passes if phone_number is *nil* or empty string

Answer (score 2):

Rails provides it out of the box. Check the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

```
validates_uniqueness_of :phone_number, :allow_blank => true
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by a brief explanation.

Comment: @dgvid: I think for this trivial stuffs its better to follow already rich documentations like http://apidock.com/rails or http://api.rubyonrails.org/